# Label inside top left corner of polygons using MapInfo Professional?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, labeling, mapinfo

Does anyone know of a tool or procedure to automatically place a label in the corner of a polygon, rather than at the centroid?

I am using Mapinfo and know that I can manually place the label there, but I have a lot of polygons and would prefer to do it automatically, especially as the polygons change every so often.

Even better would be a way to do this in ArcGIS Desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to [the Maplex Extension for ArcMap](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/extensions/maplex/index.html) you can pretty much do anything you can imagine when it comes to labeling.

Comment: UPDATE: MAPLEX is the default labeling engine in ArcMap Desktop 10.1, which is scheduled for June 2012. http://resourcesbeta.arcgis.com/en/help/pdf/whats_new_in_arcgis.pdf (Page 4)

Answer (score 2):

You can label in a position.

Go into layer control (right click) and then select the layer you want, then the label button.  IN there, is all the positioning you need.

In MapBasic, you can do the following in the MapBasic window (very easy) or you can script it:

- Loop through your objects in the layer you want to label
- get the objects x,y you want (using ObjectInfo if I remember correctly)
- then adjust the label based on that.

Code to adjust is:

```
Set Map Layer 1 Label Object 1 
    Visibility On 
    Anchor (0, 85) ’anchor the label at this (x,y)
```

[MapBasic User/Reference Guide](http://reference.mapinfo.com/software/mapbasic/english/9_0/MB_UG.pdf)

You could also look at this; trial version is free, in case it works for you: evermap.com/evername.asp

Comment: That only allows you to chose the placement relative to the centroid from what I can see.  I thought there may be an aftermarket add on or tool to do what I want.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to edit the initial answer - I hadn't thought of using object info.